# Liquibase BRIN and HASH index for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm trying to add a BRIN index for my database column.

```
- createIndex:
    indexName: titles_updated_at_idx
    tableName: titles
    columns:
    - name: updated_at
      type: DATETIME
```

How do I do that using Liquibase?

Comment: you will need a SQL change. In the XML format that would be `<sql>create index ... using brin ...</sql>` I don't use the other formats, so I don't know what the corresponding element in YAML (?) that would be

Comment: You sure can use `sql` for it. Check out the `Yaml sample` tab https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html